# Android- Json Parsing Through Exception

Tags: java, android, json

**Android-**

I am getting JSON response following. I have button when i click with Specific ID (1,1015,1016 see below). it will return the inner Json objects.

I have a problem only in getting that Specific Ids(Json)

```
[
        {
            "1":
            [
                {
                    "a": "a",
                    "b": 1,
                    "c": "1",
                    "d": "1-1-1-1"
                },
                {
                    "a": "a",
                    "b": 6,
                    "c": "2",
                    "d": "1-1-1",
                    "e": "Meals"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "1015":
            [
            ]
        },
        {
            "1016":
            [
                {
                    "a": "a",
                    "b": 6,
                    "c": "2",
                    "d": "1-1-1",
                    "e": "Meals1234"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "1012":
            [
                {
                    "a": "venky",
                    "b": 6,
                    "c": "2",
                    "d": "1-1-1",
                    "e": "Meals"
                },
                {
                    "a": "venky2",
                    "b": 45,
                    "c": "2",
                    "d": "1-1-1",
                    "e": "Meals"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "1011":
            [
                {
                   "a": "a",
                    "b": 6,
                    "c": "2",
                    "d": "1-1-1",
                    "e": "Meals567"
                },
                {
                    "a": "a",
                    "b": 6,
                    "c": "2",
                    "d": "1-1-1",
                    "e": "Meals08676"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I write the Java Code for JSON parsing follows

```
public void load_whole_JsonData() {
        String number = ET_number.getText().toString().trim(); // edittext number is 1 (for example)
        JSONArray jsonArray1;
        JSONObject obj1; 
        JSONArray jsonArray2;
        try {
            jsonArray1=new JSONArray(JsonResponse); // parse the Json response here
            obj1=new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonArray2= jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(number); //number is IDs :  1 , 1015,1016 
                    Log.v("test", "i"+i+ " obj1 "+jsonArray2);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.v("test", "exception "+e);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("MTV", "JsonParser exception" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting the Correct output but Catch throws because of

```
jsonArray2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(number); //number is IDs :  1 , 1015,1016
```

Output (In Logcat):

```
 V/test: i0 obj1 [{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"},{"a":"a","b":6,"c":"2","d":"1-1-1","e":"Meals"}] //This is the output

 V/test: exception org.json.JSONException: No value for 1 //catch exceptions
 V/test: exception org.json.JSONException: No value for 1
 V/test: exception org.json.JSONException: No value for 1
 V/test: exception org.json.JSONException: No value for 1
```

**If anyone have idea to get output without catch exception.** then How to get the Inner details like `[{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"},{"a":"a","b":6,"c":"2","d":"1-1-1","e":"Meals"}]`

**EDITED:**

If i give the number is 1016. it will parse only the Inner details of 1016 [{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"} (get from the whole JSON response)

Comment: You have two variables `number` with same type `String`. Are you sure your code is compiling?

Comment: First correct code in your question. Once place you have written `jsonArray2= jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(number);` and about same thing at another place you have written `obj2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(number);`. If you edit your code before posting then please do it correctly.

Comment: I just given the number for consideration (String number =1). Now i removed @Rohit5k2

Comment: Thanks. I corrected my Code@Rohit5k2

Comment: I have corrected the issue in my answer. Please try that.

Comment: Ok. i will try @Rohit5k2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because in each `JSONObject` you are trying to find an array with key `1`, which is not available. So in each `JSONObject` you need to use the correct key with with the array is associated.

Do this

```
try {
        jsonArray1=new JSONArray(JsonResponse); // parse the Json response here
        obj1=new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
            try {
                    JSONObject innerJson = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    for(Iterator<String> iter = innerJson.keys();iter.hasNext();) 
                    {
                        String key = iter.next();
                        jsonArray2 = innerJson.getJSONArray(key);
                    }
                Log.v("test", "i"+i+ " obj1 "+jsonArray2);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.v("test", "exception "+e);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v("MTV", "JsonParser exception" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Update**

```
try {
        jsonArray1=new JSONArray(JsonResponse); // parse the Json response here
        obj1=new JSONObject();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray1.length(); i++) {
            try {
                    JSONObject innerJson = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    for(Iterator<String> iter = innerJson.keys();iter.hasNext();) 
                    {
                        String key = iter.next();
                        if(!key.equalIgnoreCase(myKey)) // myKey is the key you want to parse such as 1016
                            continue;
                        jsonArray2 = innerJson.getJSONArray(key);
                    }
                Log.v("test", "i"+i+ " obj1 "+jsonArray2);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.v("test", "exception "+e);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.v("MTV", "JsonParser exception" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please try now. `keySet` method is hidden.

Comment: Where I pass the number value ? (1 or 1016 etc)

Comment: You don't have to pass it now. The method `innerJson.keys()` inside the `for` loop will take care of it automatically.

Comment: Early, I got InnerJson but i want only the given Numbers InnerJsons.

Comment: If i give the number is 1016. it will parse only the Inner details of 1016 [{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"} (refer the whole JSON response)

Comment: In that case you need to ignore other objects. See my updated answer. `myKey` will be the number you want to parse. Notice the `if` statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100975/discussion-between-venkatesh-selvam-and-rohit5k2).

Answer (score 1):

Because `JSONObject` contains dynamic name as key for `JSONArray`. so `JSONObject. keySet` to get all keys name then use it to get `JSONArray` as:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i); 
Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I pass the number value ? (1 or 1016 etc)

Comment: @VenkateshSelvam: 1 or 1016 is in `key ` and we are passing here `JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray(key);` and `jsonArray ` contains JSONArray

Comment: If i give the number is 1016. it will parse only the Inner details of 1016 [{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"} (refer the whole JSON response)

Comment: @VenkateshSelvam: No only `1016 ` add `Log.i("TAG","JSON :"+key+"--->>"+ jsonArray.toString());` now you will see both JSONArrays in Logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100973/discussion-between-venkatesh-selvam-and--k).

Answer (score 0):

Only the first object in the array has a property `"1"`. For all others you encounter in the for loop the exception will be thrown.

You may want to check if the property `number`exists in the JSON Object before you access it.

Comment: Yes,I know.  I just the given number is 1 for understanding. The Number is dynamic. So only i ask the question.

Comment: Can you explain in your question what you try to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, If i give the number is 1016. it will parse only the Inner details of 1016 [{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"} (refer the whole JSON response) @henry

Answer (score 0):

`getJSONArray` throws exceptions. Just use [`optJSONArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#optJSONArray(java.lang.String)) instead which returns null in case it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting exception because you are always accessing array with name"1" the error is in this line of code

```
 jsonArray2= jsonArray1.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(number)
```

assign 2015,2016 etc also

Comment: Please see my questions, i already told "that line gives exception".

Comment: If i give the number is 1016. it will parse only the Inner details of 1016 [{"a":"a","b":1,"c":"1","d":"1-1-1-1","e":"Meals"} (refer the whole JSON response)